# Is there a way to search unofficial repositories in launchpad?

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad, search, ubuntu-website

I was wondering if this [STDIN Plasmoid](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=92309) had been packaged by someone, so I googled for it. It seemed like it *has* been packaged as [plasma-widget-stdin](https://launchpad.net/~leviatan1/+ppa-packages). However, this (unofficial) ppa also contained a some other things that I was uninterested in (and might unintentionally upgrade).

I wanted to see if there were other ppas contained this widget, so I attempted to [search](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=plasma-widget-stdin). However, it seems that the Launchpad search only contains official packages. Is there a way to search Launchpad for unofficial packages and repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second link you gave "[plasma-widget-stdin](https://launchpad.net/~leviatan1/+ppa-packages)" can be found by searching in the main launchpad site by searching by package name(I was able to find it that way). The 3rd link goes to the Ubuntu launchpad website, which only searches Ubuntu packages.  I'm not sure how you ended up on the "official Ubuntu only site" but if you end up there in the future, look in the bottom left of the screen, you will see the Launchpad name and logo, it will get you to the main Launchpad website and you can search for unofficial packages there.  To go there directly, the website is :

[launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net)

(Which I belive answers your original question, but please read on)

---

The ppa that you linked to appears to be no longer maintained, so I would use any packages from it with extreme caution.

If you do find a (active) ppa that contains it, you can download it by

1. clicking the click just above the package list "**view package details**"
2. clicking on the package name
3. clicking on the .deb package that matches you architecture (i386 for 32bit or amd for 64bit)

I would do this with extreme caution as well, often (but not always) the other packages that are added to the ppa are dependencies of that package that you want to add and using the new package with older dependencies can be unpredictable at best;

It may fail to install at all with the error that `xx` package is needed then you will have to go back to the ppa that you download the individual package from, download the package the was the dependency, try to install it, then go back again download the dependency for the dependency, then install the dependency for the dependency, then install the dependency, then install the package you wanted(this is known in the Linux world as "dependency hell" for obvious reasons, ppa are used to prevent this problem).

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me. However, I find it a bit confusing as to whether "Ubuntu" referred to the official packages or the overall branding of the system. Thanks also for the advice on installing individual debs. As you say, I wanted to use the ppa, also so the application would be kept up to date. However, in this specific example, it seems like it hasn't been updated for four years, so I just installed it from source (using `checkinstall`).

Comment: Glad I was able to help, I have also once or twice ended up on the "Ubuntu only" website without realizing it, but I don't remember how I did it(if I had to guess it was doing a google search), then wondering why I couldn't find an unofficial ppa....BTW the "Ubuntu" refers to the official packages, Launchpad itself is a Canonical site, as far as I'm aware only Ubuntu ppa, either official or unofficial are on it so searching there will only bring up Ubuntu ppa